# Python Module Import Error "ImportError: No module named mrjob.job"

Tags: python, module, path, mrjob

System: Mac OSX 10.6.5, Python 2.6

I try to run the python script below:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

 class MRWordCounter(MRJob):
  def mapper(self, key, line):
      for word in line.split():
          yield word, 1

  def reducer(self, word, occurrences):
      yield word, sum(occurrences)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordCounter.run()
```

I get the following error:

```
:~ vskarich$ python mrjob_test.py < words
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mrjob_test.py", line 1, in <module>
   from mrjob.job import MRJob
  ImportError: No module named mrjob.job
```

I had used easy_install like so:

sudo easy_install mrjob

This command downloaded the needed .egg file, and my site-packages directory for python looks like this:

```
:~ vskarich$ cd /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages

:site-packages vskarich$ ls

PyYAML-3.09-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg  
easy-install.pth
README       
mrjob-0.2.0-py2.6.egg
boto-2.0b3-py2.6.egg     
simplejson-2.1.2-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
```

I am not sure what to do here as I am somewhat new to python; any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: well every thing look fine from here unless you run your script using python not version 2.6 , do this in your script in the first lines before the import; __import sys; print sys.path__ this will give you the PYTHONPATH from where python search the packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Make sure you don't have any file or directory permissions problems for the installed eggs and files in the `site-packages` directory.
2. If you have installed another instance of Python 2.6 (besides the Apple-supplied one in `/usr/bin/python2.6`), make sure you have installed a separate version of `easy_install` for it.  As is, your output indicates it was almost certainly installed using the Apple-supplied `easy_install` in `/usr/bin` which is for the Apple-supplied Python.  The easiest way to do that is to install the [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#distribute-setup-py) package using the new Python.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I tried `pip install mrjob`, `sudo easy_install mrjob`. It looked like it installed successfully, but when I ran a simple example script, I got the import error.

I got it to work by following the instructions at: http://pythonhosted.org//mrjob/guides/quickstart.html#installation.

In a nutshell, I cloned the source code from github and ran `python setup.py install`. My problem might be different from yours, though. There was nothing in my site-packages directory for mrjob after running pip-install and easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

mrjob package can be installed by running following command: 
**pip install mrjob** 
After installation, the error will be solved. 
It worked in my case.